# Return headers in output when running "php -f index.php"

Tags: php, command-line

I tried searching around to find an answer to this but to no avail.

I have a simples PHP script with the below code:

```php
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo "Hello";
?>
```

I then execute the file using the below command:

```
php -f index.php
```

and the output is:

```
Hello
```

My question is, is it possible to return the header I outputted using PHP, so my expected output would be something like:

```
Content-Type: application/json

Hello
```

Comment: @mario Thanks! I tried php-cgi but with the -f option, removed and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using php-cgi without the -f option:

```
php-cgi index.php
```

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.3
Content-Type: application/json

Hello
```